# Not able to declare array as public VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

When I tried to declare the array as public from the `Main Sub()` in *Sheet1* it's throwing a compile error:

> "Arrays not allowed as Public Members of object Modules".

What I am trying to do is declare an array whose elements can be calculated/manipulated from any modules added in VBA project.

```
Public Segment() As String

Public SegCount As Integer

Sub EDI()
   'calls to subroutines placed in modules
End Sub
```

Comment: what are the motives of changing the accepted anser to a different one after almost 2 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the usual workaround woud be using a variant.

```
Public MyArray as Variant
```

What can go wrong with that ? well a lot , so preferably pass arrays as arguments (to subs `byval a() as string` , BUT to functions you can only `byval a as variant` (could be a `byref` if you get an error))

note : works too (inside a module):

```
Option Explicit

Public rott() As String 'for a dynamyc array
'Public rott(1 to 10) As String 'for a fixed size array 

Sub ff()
ReDim rott(1 To 10) 'or redim preserve rott (1 to 10) if you want to keep values (note you can only redilm the last dimension of the array).
Debug.Print rott(1)
End Sub
```

note 2 : anything stoping the code would reset the public values....

Comment: The "usual workaround" does not work. You can not assign by index to the array in the Variant. It just doesn't take. VBA sniffs you out and stops you.

Comment: my mistacke (i guess), declare it on top of a module, not a sheet

Answer (score 1):

Insert a standard coding Module - it will become a `Module1` then stick `Public Segment() As String` on top of that module... such as

[image]