# VBA Array Public Method cant be modified by components

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I'm working with a rather complex problem in VBA and I decided to structure it in different classes.
One of the classes containd an array and I need to modify the component individualy outside the class.

The problem can de reduced to the definition of the class

```
Public a As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim a(5) As Double

    ' Set some value
    a(1) = 20
End Sub
```

And a sub to access the data:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim b As New DummyTest

    b.a(4) = 7

    Debug.Print (b.a(1))
    Debug.Print (b.a(4))

End Sub
```

The result on the debug window is *20 0*. I've checked this result with an inspection and confirm that the property *a* cannot be modified from the exterior of the class.
Funny part is that the property can be modified if replaced by other array, for example:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim b As New DummyTest

    b.a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    Debug.Print (b.a(1))
    Debug.Print (b.a(4))

End Sub
```

Behaves as expected. I'm confused as element access is allowed inside the class context and in any other situation, but in this specific case it doesn't wotk. There is no error msg, it simply refuses to change the content of the array.

I'll find work around solutions but missing this way to access data is being a really PITA.

Hope you can help me with this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your "property" is breaking encapsulation, which pretty much defeats its entire purpose.

> ```
> Public a As Variant
> ```

From a public interface standpoint, this is a read-write property (if you added a new class module with `Implements DummyTest` you'd have to add `Property Get` and `Property Let` members for it). From the class' standpoint, it's a *public instance field*.

When a class encapsulates an array, a collection, a dictionary, or any other data structure, the last thing you want is for that data structure to be publicly exposed, with anyone anywhere being able to just overwrite the class' entire internal state as it pleases - you're not getting any of the advantages of classes that way.

First step to proper encapsulation is to make the instance field `Private`. Next step is to expose actual `Property` accessors. You want the array data to be writable? Expose an indexed `Property Let` member for it.

```
Private a As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim a(0 To 10)
End Sub

Public Property Get Value(ByVal index As Long) As Variant
    Value = a(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Value(ByVal index As Long, ByVal newvalue As Variant)
    a(index) = newvalue
End Property
```

This code behaves exactly as advertised:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim b As DummyTest
    Set b = New DummyTest

    b.Value(4) = 7

    Debug.Print b.Value(1)
    Debug.Print b.Value(4)

End Sub
```

Note that because the array is encapsulated, that client code is absolutely unable to re-assign the array itself: the array is abstracted away and only accessible through the means exposed by the class.

Comment: I didn't mean touse the encapsulation. I just wanted to struct the data and save be some typing. I'm aware that his way of expose attributes of the class may be unorthodox but doing your way implies to write 6 aditionals lines of code for each of the arrays (and there are 20 or so, which means a lot of typing). Also by doing this way means that I lost the posibility to treat these attributes as arrays anymore, which is something I still want to use in some cases.

Comment: @sphere I'm showing you how it works, *correctly*. Feel free to use global variables instead if it's keystrokes you're looking to save.

Comment: Sounds very much like an X-Y problem

Comment: Thank you @Mathieu I appreciate your opinion! Sadly I dont think global will do the job, as I need multiple instances of this class, each of those with different values. Nevertheless thank you for the tips!

Comment: @sphere my advice remains to come up with a solid and properly encapsulated data structure. If there are 20 arrays and you're looking at 20 such indexed properties, then the data structure is wrong and it's not an array you need to encapsulate, but a dictionary. Or a jagged array perhaps - in any case that's not the scenario laid out in the OP.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Much better to use dictionaries and some functiones to handle the them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reference variable in VBA must be declared, so that we know what type of object we are referring to

i.e. Dim b As DummyTest  ' No new required in this step

Before using a declared reference to store information create an instance of the Class.

i.e. Set b = New DummyTest

This might seem confusing but is actually very logical.  Because b is a Class the Dim statement sets up b to hold the address of a DummyTest object.  At the time of the Dim statement no object has been created (no memory allocated)  so the address of b is nothing (no value or null).  The set statement tells VBA to create an instance of your DummyTest class (allocate the memory it needs) and puts the address of the instance (memory) into variable b.  Then because VBA knows that b points to an instance of a class you never see the address of b when you  use it, just the data to which b is pointing.  You can get the the address b is holding using the function Objptr but this is only something you would do in very special/specific circumstances

Comment: The `As New` declaration sure isn't helping, but separating declaration from assignment makes no difference.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon good catch.  My brain is a bit fried at the moment as I'm converting some Advent of code solutions I wrote in VBA into C# and Nim.  In the process I'm learinng about assumptions I didn't know I'd made..

Comment: I've tried the solution you propose with the same result. I thought that using:
Set b as **new** Dummy test
already allocate the part. But I'll check if something can be done with the Objptr

Comment: There is absolutely no need for you to be using Objptr in your current example.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, No! My encapsulation! It's broken! What ever shall I do??? Now I'm "incorrect"! :(

Who cares? Unless you're writing an API for consumption and need to separate interface and implementation. "But now someone could change the whole dang array via a public member!" Yeah and they also could by hitting Alt-F11...

If you just want a lightweight package to, say, ship around an evolving set of parameters through several function calls--which might include arrays--it can get unpleasant.

You can't have arrays as public fields in a class. Even if you hide them as Variant types ([Accessing Public Variant Array from Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873955/accessing-public-variant-array-from-module): "But since you declared as Variant, the compiler didn't complain, but the assignment just doesn't work."). (I just wasted 20 minutes trying to figure out why the assignment to myclass.myarrayinapublicvariant(i) = 3.1415 just wouldn't take.) (An answer here incorrectly says you can work around: [Not able to declare array as public VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757875/not-able-to-declare-array-as-public-vba) . And here too: [Creating VB array that is public, within class module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882691/creating-vb-array-that-is-public-within-class-module) .)

You can do the whole object thing and create Gets and Lets--but you'll likely need a pair for the array and another pair for array elements. And now you've got 12 lines of code instead of 1--for. every. single. array. And how much extra memory does that take if you have a lot of these?? (I genuinely don't know and do wonder.)

You can stick arrays in user defined "Types". But then you don't get any accessory functions. And if you happen to want any self referential or mutually referential types (between Types or between a Type and a Class), then you're out of luck.

For my project, there just is no clean solution.

Another thread asks if there is a technical reason for this ([Is there a technical reason why I cannot declare a public array in a VBA class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033805/is-there-a-technical-reason-why-i-cannot-declare-a-public-array-in-a-vba-class)) and no one came through with the answer then. But I would bet that some COM-Interface genius out there (certainly not me) could explain it if they noticed the question.

Comment: That _someone_ isn't the user, it's you. Future you. A colleague, or your eventual replacement. You're not writing code for a compiler to build and run, you're writing code so that when you read it you (or future you, or your eventual replacement) know what it's for and what it does at a glance, which doesn't happen with ambiguously written code where everything is public or global and nobody cares because it works anyway. Consider accepting the (correct and nicely explained) answer you got on that linked question, and thanks for that random downvote, cheers!